# Unable to create a custom Tauri window title bar in Sveltekit

Tags: sveltekit, tauri

I have setup a Sveltekit-Tauri app and want to create a custom title bar. I followed the instructions as per Tauri's official page. The html and css works. But the javascript shows an error.

```
<script>

 import { appWindow } from '@tauri-apps/api/window'
document
  .getElementById('titlebar-minimize')
  .addEventListener('click', () => appWindow.minimize())
document
  .getElementById('titlebar-maximize')
  .addEventListener('click', () => appWindow.toggleMaximize())
document
  .getElementById('titlebar-close')
  .addEventListener('click', () => appWindow.close())
</script>

<div data-tauri-drag-region class="titlebar">
    <div class="titlebar-button" id="titlebar-minimize">
        <img
            src="https://api.iconify.design/mdi:window-minimize.svg"
            alt="minimize"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="titlebar-button" id="titlebar-maximize">
        <img
            src="https://api.iconify.design/mdi:window-maximize.svg"
            alt="maximize"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="titlebar-button" id="titlebar-close">
        <img src="https://api.iconify.design/mdi:close.svg" alt="close" />
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    /* MENU TITLE BAR */
    .titlebar {
        height: 30px;
        background: #329ea3;
        user-select: none;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    .titlebar-button {
        display: inline-flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
    }
    .titlebar-button:hover {
        background: #5bbec3;
    }
</style>
```

I also configured the tauri.config.json file

```
"windows": [
      {
        "fullscreen": false,
        "height": 600,
        "resizable": true,
        "maximized": true,
        "width": 800,
        "decorations": false,
        "all": false,
        "close": true,
        "hide": true,
        "show": true,
        "maximize": true,
        "minimize": true,
        "unmaximize": true,
        "unminimize": true,
        "startDragging": true
      }
    ]
```

Tried putting javascript code on a default page as well as a separate svelte file. Same issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgUOn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONn6q.png)

I think there is an issue with the script/js section, but I can't understand what exactly since it's the code suggested by Tauri.

Answer (score 1):

You should add your click handlers using Svelte's syntax rather than trying to add event listeners directly on the DOM.

Try simplifying your code to the following:

```html
<script>
  import { appWindow } from '@tauri-apps/api/window'
</script>

<div data-tauri-drag-region class="titlebar">
    <div class="titlebar-button" id="titlebar-minimize" on:click={() => appWindow.minimize()}>
        <img
            src="https://api.iconify.design/mdi:window-minimize.svg"
            alt="minimize"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="titlebar-button" id="titlebar-maximize" on:click={() => appWindow.toggleMaximize()}>
        <img
            src="https://api.iconify.design/mdi:window-maximize.svg"
            alt="maximize"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="titlebar-button" id="titlebar-close" on:click={() => appWindow.close()}>
        <img src="https://api.iconify.design/mdi:close.svg" alt="close" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can just do ``on:click={appWindow.close}`` right?

Comment: @ihsan yes, you can either use a function pointer as you did, or a lambda like in my code, both should work :)